# USB Multiwriter - how to select a new ISO

Tags: usb, 17.10, live-usb, multiwriter

I have successfully created a live usb of Ubuntu Kylin. Now I want to use it again for a different iso.

But I cannot select a new iso (un-select the previously selected iso).

The **start copy** button initially opened a file selector. Now it tries to write the old iso directly - which gives an error instead of writing it only because I have moved that iso.

[image]

[image]

How to select a new iso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly there was a bug with this program in 17.10.

In 18.04 it has a separate button (left of the "Start Copying" button) with the option to select ("import") a new iso.

[image]

Its version is 3.28.0-1.